# Understanding how integration by parts is done in Gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The the Gamma function is defined as...

[image: formula1]
.

I'm looking into how the *Gauss representation* of the Gamma function is derived and the first step is integration by parts. No steps are shown and the following is the result of applying integration by parts...

[image: form2]
.

I'm confused as to how these values were derived. This is my take on it...

[image: u]
.

[image: dv]
.

I imagine this is how they chose *u* and *dv*, which means...

[image: v]
.

[image: du]
.

I am not sure how they got *du*. I tried deriving *u* and ended up at...

$e[n \ln(1-t/n)]$

and then ended up getting a different answer after attempting to derive it. Can someone show me how *du* is derived, or show me where I am going wrong, so that I can complete the parts by integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is $$\frac {du}{dt}=\frac d{dt}\left(\left(1-\frac tn\right)^n\right)=n\left(1-\frac tn\right)^{n-1}\times\frac d{dt}\left(1-\frac tn\right)$$by the chain rule$$=n\left(1-\frac tn\right)^{n-1}\times-\frac1n=-\left(1-\frac tn\right)^{n-1}$$which should be as required for your integration. (I notice they have written this term with a $\frac nn$ in front, which is basically redundant.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to differentiate $u = \left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^n$ with respect to $t$. Just use the power rule and chain rule: $$\frac{du}{dt} = n \left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n-1}\times (-1/n) = - \left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n-1}.$$